# How do I add a class to a JointJS cell?

Tags: svg, jointjs

I can use the `attr` method to change attributes of a cell, e.g. to set the stroke of a link:

```
conn.attr({'.connection': { stroke: 'red' }});
```

But I would rather set such attributes in the css file, e.g. as in this

```
.connection {
    stroke: #999;
}

.connection.error {
    stroke: #F00;
}
```

Is there a way to add such classes to the generated SVG?

I tried

```
conn.attr({'.connection': { class: 'error' }});
```

but that removes the `.connection`  class, which is important. It works to write

```
conn.attr({'.connection': { class: 'connection error' }});
```

but clearly that will not scale to having multiple orthogonal classes (`error`, `highlighted`...)

Comment: Did you try [Vectorizer > addClass(className)](http://jointjs.com/api#v:addClass)?

Comment: No. I was under the impression that `Vectorizer` will work on the DOM objects, which are owned by the view (`ElementView`), while the above affects the model object (`Element`).

Comment: Can you provide JSFiddle?

Comment: Hmm, the real code is of course part of something relatively large. Rebuilding that will take a while.

Comment: Hmm, you might be right after all, see my answer (about which I am not happy.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one of the [official demos](http://www.jointjs.com/demos/logic) I find this code:

```
function toggleLive(model, signal) {
    // add 'live' class to the element if there is a positive signal
    V(paper.findViewByModel(model).el).toggleClass('live', signal > 0);
}
```

I must say that this looks rather like a violation of the model-view separation to me to directly interact with the view this way, but if that is used in the official code then I conclude that this is the most idiomatic way.

Comment: Thank you for finding this hidden gem. jQuery can also be used: `$(paper.findViewByModel(model).el).toggleClass('live')`. I know it looks wrong but it's especially useful to associate _data_ or other stuff to it (no `data` function in Vectorizer). If we use use the _$el_ jQuery reference, it becomes even simpler: `paper.findViewByModel(model).$el.data('liveID', 14214)`.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone looking for answer to this 2015 question in 2018, try this out as well.

I had a similar problem and solved it using `highlighters`.

```
cellView.highlight(null, {
    highlighter: {
        name: 'addClass',
        options: {
            className: 'some-custom-class'
        }
    }
});
```

The above code will add a class `some-custom-class` to the cell view element. To remove the class, use `cellView.unhighlight(...)` method with the exact same arguments. Note that now it'll only remove `some-custom-class` and other classes if present will stay as it is.

Ref: https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.1/joint.html#highlighters.addClass